# How to add 2 addeventlisteners to work together (e.g.: run event on dblclick when mouse pointer is at left side of screen)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover, onmouseover, ondblclick

New to JavaScript, trying to figure out how to combine addEventListener events.

For example, I want to trigger something when I double-click the side of the screen, within 30 or 40 pixels.

I assume I need to combine these somehow:

- `document.addEventListener("dblclick",function (event) {`
- `document.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {`

How is that done? I'm also struggling to get that mouseover working even alone, if anyone cares to take a stab at it!

Comment: No, no need to combine with any mousemove handler. Click and double click events already give you access to the click coordinates. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need mouseover event listener to do that.

Method 1:
First create 30-40pixel `div` element, with `position:fixed`.
Then add double click event to that `div` element.

Method 2:
Add doubleclick event to the document, read `event.clientX` (or `event.screenX`).
`if (event.clientX < 30)`, run what you want.

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick",function (event) { 
        if(event.clientX < 30 ) {
        // some logic
        }
})
```

Comment: Method 2 is working for me, and I like that i don't need to add that div into the HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can listen for double click events and get the mouse x coordinate (which you can then use to check if it's within 30 or 40 pixels of the left side).

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('body');
elem.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
  console.log(e.clientX);
});
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px;">
  Double click to log mouse x coordinate.
</div>
```